# MySQL auto-increment not working on INT(12)

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

Auto-increment of primary key is disabled When I'm using custom integer like INT(12) in MySQL (5.7.17) . My primary key should have following features:

```
`ID` int(12) unsigned zerofill NOT NUL
```

Comment: `NOT NUL` <-- is this a typo?

Comment: how do u created through query or phpmyadmin

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah it's typo and cannot null

Comment: @itsme This is an old database that has already been created through phpmyadmin. I changed the type of tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: try this 
If using InnoDB, check the status monitor (SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS) right after you execute the alter. It should tell you if it's because of the FK constraint. You may need to drop the constraints, alter the column and create them again.

Comment: `INT(anything) UNSIGNED` still has a maximum value of (2^32)-1 = 4294967295.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was solved. The reason for this was because of the alter script in MySQL Workbench that removes autoincrement and it seems a bug.